# Kendo Grid Checkbox on header does not select all rows

Tags: javascript, c#, kendo-ui, kendo-grid, kendo-asp.net-mvc

I am using Kendo ui on my project and I have a problem on grid. I added checkbox selection to grid but it does not work. My code is like below;

```
  @(Html.Kendo().Grid<UserCommentListViewModel>()
    .Name("CommentGrid")
                            .DataSource(ds => ds
                            .Ajax()
                            .PageSize(20)

                            .Model(model => model.Id(p => p.CommentId))
                             .Batch(true)
                            .ServerOperation(false)
                            .Events(events => events.Error("error_handler"))
                            .Read(r => r.Action("GetUserComments", "CommentManagement").Data("getFilterCriteria")))
    .Columns(columns =>
    {
        columns.Select().Width(50);
        columns.Bound(p => p.UserId).Width(105).Title("Müşteri Id").Filterable(ftb => ftb.Cell(cell => cell.ShowOperators(false)));
        columns.Bound(p => p.UserMail).Width(105).Title("Müşteri E-Posta").Filterable(ftb => ftb.Cell(cell => cell.Operator("contains").SuggestionOperator(FilterType.Contains)));
        columns.Bound(p => p.Comment).Width(200).Title("Yorum").
        Filterable(ftb => ftb.Cell(cell => cell.Operator("contains").SuggestionOperator(FilterType.Contains)));
        columns.Bound(p => p.CommentCreatedTime).Width(100).Title("Oluşturulma Tarihi").Filterable(ftb => ftb.Cell(cell => cell.ShowOperators(false))).Format("{0:dd/MM/yyyy}");
        columns.Command(command =>
        {
            command.Custom("Düzenle").Click("commentEdit");
            command.Custom("Yayından Geri Al").Click("commentUnpublish");
            command.Custom("Kara Listeye Ekle").Click("commentBlackList");
        }).Width(180).Title("İşlemler");

    })
    .PersistSelection()
    .Events(events=>events.DataBound("onDataBound").Change("onChange"))
    //.Editable(editable => editable.Mode(GridEditMode.PopUp))
    .Filterable(ftb => ftb.Mode(GridFilterMode.Row))
    .ToolBar(toolbar =>
    {
        toolbar.Excel();

    })

    .Excel(excel => excel
    .AllPages(true)
    .ProxyURL(Url.Action("CommentList_Excel_Save", "CommentManagement"))
    .ForceProxy(true)
    .FileName("UserCommentList.xlsx"))
       .Pageable(x =>
       x.PageSizes(new[] { 20, 40, 60 })
       .Info(true)
       .Refresh(true)
      .Messages(m =>
      { m.ItemsPerPage("Items Per Page"); }))
    .NoRecords("Kayıt bulunamadı")
    .Deferred()
)
```

[image]

Could you help me about this bug. I am using Kendo 2017.2.621 version. Also i added this code ( `$("#grid").table.on("click", ".k-checkbox", selectRow);`) to script part, again same. Header checkbox does not select all checkbox on rows.

Comment: What about `$("#grid").on("click", ".k-checkbox", selectRow);`?

Comment: Yes this way works, thanks but header checkbox still does not select all functionality. I am trying official websites of telerik. How can i handle select all functionality?

Comment: Idk, where is your `selectRow` func? The problem is probably there.

Comment: I don't add this method to post, problem is not about this selectRow method.